# Databricks: Convert a sql view to python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, databricks

I have created an sql view in databricks. Is it possible to assign the view to a python dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df = spark.sql('select * from myViewName')
```